# Python awk command

Tags: python

```
import os
import sys

os.system ('kill "$(ps aux | grep snmp | awk '"{print $2}"' | head -n1)"')
```

I am trying to kill a process in python, but I have this error with this line:

```
awk: line 2: missing } near end of file
sh: 1: kill: Illegal number
```

The problem comes from the awk command, I don't know the exact syntax.
Can you help me please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: need to send the quotes with escape character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'` around `awk '` terminates the Python string, so you end up with a [concatenation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/string-catenation.html) of `'kill "$(ps aux | grep snmp | awk '`, `"{print $2}"`, and `' | head -n1)"'`, basically trying to execute:

```
$ kill "$(ps aux | grep snmp | awk {print $2} | head -n1)"
```

where `{` is parsed as shell syntax.

This should work:

```
os.system('kill "$(ps aux | grep snmp| awk \'{print $2}\' | head -n1)"')
```

A possibly better approach would be to use [pkill](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html):

```
os.system('pkill snmp')
```

Comment: Thank you! But what is the correct syntax in this case?

Comment: And corrected my first assumption, where I had misunderstood how Python parses string literals. :))

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system("ps -C snmp -o pid=|xargs kill -9")
```

I hope this might help